# DigitalOcean DNS can new cname record conflict with existing wildcard cname record

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, wildcard, digital-ocean

I am having an existing wildcard CNAME record that goes like *.example.com. I wanted to add another CNAME record to map from an address like app.example.com to some.example.com. Will this create conflicts on the DNS records?

Answer (score 3):

A specific entry always overrides a wildcard, so app.domain.com will take priority on *.domain.com

See [chapter 4.3.3 of RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-4.3.3).

> Wildcard RRs do not apply:
>
> - When the query is in another zone.  That is, delegation cancels
>   the wildcard defaults.
> - When the query name or a name between the wildcard domain and
>   the query name is know to exist.  For example, if a wildcard
>   RR has an owner name of "*.X", and the zone also contains RRs
>   attached to B.X, the wildcards would apply to queries for name
>   Z.X (presuming there is no explicit information for Z.X), but
>   not to B.X, A.B.X, or X.